# How to fix GNU/Make "Too many open files. Stop." errors without increasing the open file limit?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am currently trying to compile a project for an nRF52 board. When using `make clean`, I get the error message `Makefile.common:12: *** Too many open files.  Stop.` (Line 12 of Makefile.common just says `include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)Makefile.posix`).

Every solution I can find online to this problem involves increasing the number of files the system can open at once. Unfortunately, I tried increasing it all the way to 20000 (which is apparently enough to overload the memory on my computer), and it still gave the same error message. So I don't think this is a practical solution in my case, and that this problem indicates something wrong with the makefile itself. Is there a culprit that would cause this to happen?

In case it's important, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The makefile is pasted below.

```
TARGETS          := nrf52832_xxaa
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY := _build

SDK_ROOT := $(realpath ../../../../../..)
PROJ_DIR := ../../..

$(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/nrf52832_xxaa.out: \
  LINKER_SCRIPT  := ble_app_hrs_gcc_nrf52.ld

# Source files common to all targets
SRC_FILES += \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/modules/nrfx/mdk/gcc_startup_nrf52.S \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/button/app_button.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/util/app_error.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/util/app_error_weak.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/scheduler/app_scheduler.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/timer/app_timer.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/util/app_util_platform.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/crc16/crc16.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/fds/fds.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/hardfault/hardfault_implementation.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/util/nrf_assert.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/fstorage/fstorage.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/experimental_memobj/nrf_memobj.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/pwr_mgmt/nrf_pwr_mgmt.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/sensorsim/sensorsim.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/drivers_nrf/nrf_drv_clock.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/drivers_nrf/nrfx_drv_gpiote.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/drivers_nrf/nrfx_uart.c \
  $(PROJ_DIR)/main.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/external/segger_rtt/SEGGER_RTT.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/external/segger_rtt/SEGGER_RTT_Syscalls_GCC.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/external/segger_rtt/SEGGER_RTT_printf.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/common/ble_advdata.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_advertising/ble_advertising.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/common/ble_conn_params.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/common/ble_conn_state.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/common/ble_srv_common.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/gatt_cache_manager.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/gatts_cache_manager.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/id_manager.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/peer_data_storage.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/peer_database.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/peer_id.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/peer_manager.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/pm_buffer.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/pm_mutex.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/security_dispatcher.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager/security_manager.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_bas/ble_bas.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_dis/ble_dis.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_hrs/ble_hrs.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/softdevice/common/softdevice_handler/softdevice_handler.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/softdevice/common/softdevice_handler/softdevice_handler_appsh.c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/nfc_ble_pair_msg.c \


# Include folders common to all targets
INC_FOLDERS += \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/generic/message \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/t2t_lib \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_ancs_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_ias_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/pwm \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/softdevice/s132/headers/nrf52 \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/drivers_nrf/hal \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_gls \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/fstorage \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/text \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/gpiote \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/bootloader_dfu \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/generic/record \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_advertising \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_bas_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/modules/nrfx/drivers/include \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/experimental_task_manager \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_hrs_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/le_oob_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/queue \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/pwr_mgmt \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_dtm \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/toolchain/CMSIS/include \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_rscs_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/common \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_lls \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/ac_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_bas \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/experimental_section_vars \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/softdevice/s132/headers \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_ans_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/slip \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/drivers_nrf/delay \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/mem_manager \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_nus_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/softdevice/common \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_ias \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/low_power_pwm \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/ep_oob_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/parser/message \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/parser/record \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_dfu \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/scheduler \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_lbs \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_hts \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/crc16 \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/t2t_parser \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/util \
  ../config \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/ecc \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/hardfault \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_cscs \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/hci \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/timer \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/led_softblink \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/parser \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_cts_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/le_oob_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_nus \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/twi_mngr \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_hids \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/strerror \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/crc32 \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/ble_oob_advdata \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/usbd/class/audio \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/sensorsim \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/t2t_lib \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/peer_manager \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_tps \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_dis \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/uri \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/button \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/twi \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/ep_oob_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/external/segger_rtt \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_lbs_c \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/sha256 \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_racp \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/libraries/fds \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/launchapp \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_rscs \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/hs_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/t2t_lib/hal_t2t \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/nfc/ndef/connection_handover/ac_rec \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/ble/ble_services/ble_hrs \

# Libraries common to all targets
LIB_FILES += \

# Optimization flags
OPT = -O3 -g3
# Uncomment the line below to enable link time optimization
#OPT += -flto

# C flags common to all targets
CFLAGS += $(OPT)
CFLAGS += -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10040
CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_GPIO_AS_PINRESET
CFLAGS += -DFLOAT_ABI_HARD
CFLAGS += -DNRF52
CFLAGS += -DNRF52832_XXAA
CFLAGS += -DNRF52_PAN_74
CFLAGS += -DNRF_SD_BLE_API_VERSION=6
CFLAGS += -DS132
CFLAGS += -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
CFLAGS += -DSWI_DISABLE0
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
# keep every function in a separate section, this allows linker to discard unused ones
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing
CFLAGS += -fno-builtin -fshort-enums

# C++ flags common to all targets
CXXFLAGS += $(OPT)

# Assembler flags common to all targets
ASMFLAGS += -g3
ASMFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
ASMFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs
ASMFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
ASMFLAGS += -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD
ASMFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10040
ASMFLAGS += -DCONFIG_GPIO_AS_PINRESET
ASMFLAGS += -DFLOAT_ABI_HARD
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF52
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF52832_XXAA
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF52_PAN_74
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF_SD_BLE_API_VERSION=6
ASMFLAGS += -DS132
ASMFLAGS += -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
ASMFLAGS += -DSWI_DISABLE0

# Linker flags
LDFLAGS += $(OPT)
LDFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -L$(SDK_ROOT)/modules/nrfx/mdk -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
LDFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
LDFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
# let linker dump unused sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
# use newlib in nano version
LDFLAGS += --specs=nano.specs

nrf52832_xxaa: CFLAGS += -D__HEAP_SIZE=8192
nrf52832_xxaa: CFLAGS += -D__STACK_SIZE=8192
nrf52832_xxaa: ASMFLAGS += -D__HEAP_SIZE=8192
nrf52832_xxaa: ASMFLAGS += -D__STACK_SIZE=8192

# Add standard libraries at the very end of the linker input, after all objects
# that may need symbols provided by these libraries.
LIB_FILES += -lc -lnosys -lm


.PHONY: default help

# Default target - first one defined
default: nrf52832_xxaa

# Print all targets that can be built
help:
    @echo following targets are available:
    @echo       nrf52832_xxaa
    @echo       flash_softdevice
    @echo       sdk_config - starting external tool for editing sdk_config.h
    @echo       flash      - flashing binary

TEMPLATE_PATH := $(SDK_ROOT)/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common

#echo $(TEMPLATE_PATH)

include $(TEMPLATE_PATH) # /Makefile.common

$(foreach target, $(TARGETS), $(call define_target, $(target)))

.PHONY: flash flash_softdevice erase

# Flash the program
flash: $(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/nrf52832_xxaa.hex
    @echo Flashing: $<
    nrfjprog -f nrf52 --program $< --sectorerase
    nrfjprog -f nrf52 --reset

# Flash softdevice
flash_softdevice:
    @echo Flashing: s132_nrf52_6.0.0_softdevice.hex
    nrfjprog -f nrf52 --program $(SDK_ROOT)/components/softdevice/s132/hex/s132_nrf52_6.0.0_softdevice.hex --sectorerase
    nrfjprog -f nrf52 --reset

erase:
    nrfjprog -f nrf52 --eraseall

SDK_CONFIG_FILE := ../config/sdk_config.h
CMSIS_CONFIG_TOOL := $(SDK_ROOT)/external_tools/cmsisconfig/CMSIS_Configuration_Wizard.jar
sdk_config:
    java -jar $(CMSIS_CONFIG_TOOL) $(SDK_CONFIG_FILE)
```

Comment: Did you consider writing your own `Makefile` by hand without any `include` from your SDK? Also, show the *commands* started by `make` and your `make` command in your question, to provide some [MCVE]. So **edit your question** to improve it before its get closed.

Comment: I already put the entire input and output generated by make in the question. I don't know what else I could possibly even put into the question.

Comment: What is the output of `make` ? What are the lines around 12 in `Makefile.common`? Also consider removing every `@` in the `Makefile`. Use  `make --trace` and [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` to debug your `Makefile` ; but **I recommend writing your `Makefile` by yourself**. Your current solution probably contains lot of useless stuff, and your question is *not* an [MCVE] but should be one

Comment: Perhaps using `xargs`  with `rm` and maybe `find` in your `Makefile` could solve your issue, which could be something other than a `make` related bug

Comment: We don't know (and probably don't have access to) `Makefile.common` and `Makefile.posix`. So we can't help you without knowing them. And you should provide some [MCVE], and so far you did not. Or ask help from the support of the company providing your SDK and its `Makefile.common`  & `Makefile.posix`

Comment: Blind guess: for `clean` your `Makefile.common` or `Makefile.posix` contains a long `$(RM)` command. You could split it into several ones. Or you have an infinite loop of `include`-s in your makefiles

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can imagine you getting that error is if you have an `include` loop in your makefile.  That is, either a makefile includes itself, or makefile `A` has `include B` and makefile `B` has `include A`.

You don't show the content of `Makefile.posix` but if it includes `Makefile.common` you could have the latter problem.

Another alternative is based on this in your example which looks wrong:

```
TEMPLATE_PATH := $(SDK_ROOT)/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common

include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)
```

then you say in `Makefile.common` you have:

```
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)Makefile.posix
```

This is wrong since `TEMPLATE_PATH` is not a directory, it's a file; this would expand to:

```
include /sdk/root/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.commonMakefile.posix
```

which is clearly wrong.

But consider this: what if you have a trailing space in TEMPLATE_PATH, so it's like this:

```
TEMPLATE_PATH := $(SDK_ROOT)/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common #<-space here
```

Note you don't need the comment; make always preserves trailing spaces even if there's nothing else at the end of the line.  Then, the include in `Makefile.common` would expand to this:

```
include /sdk/root/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common Makefile.posix
```

which has a makefile including itself, recursively.  Eventually you'll run out of open files.